# Adding an IC to LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I've downloaded IC: LR8 from here:
https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/lr8_spice_model/74409262?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,0,20,74409262

and the zip file: LR8_demo
include the files:

- LR8.asy
- LR8_demo.asc
- LR8.sub
- LR8_demo.plt

I tried to follow the tutorials but I didn't succeed.
I can run the file LR8_demo.asc and it seems to work, but when I try to build my own circuit it just fails.\

What I've done is to put:

- LR8.asy
- LR8_demo.asc
- LR8_demo.plt

in: files/lib/sym/LR8

and I put:

- LR8.sub

in: /files/lib/sub

How can I "install" this new IC?\

The fail:

[image]

Comment: It is saying it doesn't know what model file is associated with the symbol. So you either haven't entered the model file name in the right place for the symbol, you put in the wrong name, or the file is in the wrong location, or all three.

Comment: If the example works, examine the symbol in it very carefully. I believe there are two places to enter it. In the symbol properties within the schematic it is used in and after you open up the symbol file itself in the editor where you first created the symbol. I forget if you need to enter it in both places or just one.

Comment: Where is this "***files*** /lib/sub" you're talking about? And is it "/files" or just "files"?

Comment: @DKNguyen I didn't understand, what does it mean to examine the symbol in it?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen files/ is the ltspice folder

Comment: @David Which one? In "Program Files", or its Mac equivalent (judging by the picture that's what you have, because you never specified), or "My Documents" (or equivalent)? If it's the former, you'll never see anything in LTspice.

Comment: The symbol itself had to be drawn at some point which means the graphic itself it can be opened on its own. You can do it directly from your simulation without needing to hunt down the file, I believe.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen first on Program Files, now on both, Program Files and My Documents.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes I can access the square from the add component button.//
 I don't know why, but now as I write ".op .lib LR8.sub" it seems to run. do I always have to include the line: ".lib LR8.sub" when I want to use it?

Comment: Maybe? I can never remember to be honest. I always have to fiddle with it myself. But if it wants a filename you would need the extension because LTSpice isn't very smart.

Answer (score 3):

First, there is no such thing as "installing an IC" in LTspice; that's just a 3rd party libray or symbol. LTspice has two paths: the default installation path (in Windows: *Program Files*), and the custom libraries path (in *My Documents/LTspiceXVII*). In the later updates the *My Documents* path has been modified to be in *%LocalAppData%*, which makes the *My Documents* redundant.

The two paths contain the same files, except the part responsible with the actual program (executables, uninstaller, etc). The reason was to allow users to modify their libraries and symbols without touching the system path in *Program Files*. This is why placing anything in *Program Files* will not be seen by LTspice. **Do not place anything in** ***Program Files***.

Unfortunately, that comes at a price: projects made with custom libraries and symbols, that were added in *My Documents* or *%LocalAppData%*, will not run on other computers that have the exact same 3rd party files as the creator. For this reason, the *Control Panel > Sym. & Lib. Search Paths* tab allows users to add other paths, except the two, where 3rd party libraries/symbols are stored.

This doesn't solve the mentioned problem entirely, so the tried and tested way to share projects (like the one you saved from the LTspice Group) is to keep all the *needed* 3rd party libs/syms in the same folder as the project. Looking at your archive, you'll see that there is a schematic (the "demo"), a custom symbol (*LR8.asy*), and a custom library (a library can hold one or more subcircuits, here *LR8.sub*). Since all files are local relative to the project, they can be archived and sent to any other PC and they will run out of the box.

This is why the demo runs, but when you try to make your own schematic, it fails. If you look closely in the demo schematic, the symbol has no settings other than the name to match the `.subckt` definition inside the *LR8.sub* file. Then there is a SPICE directive: `.lib LR8.sub`.

This is what happens: a symbol is a *caller*, an entity that, when present, needs to call a subcircuit, or a model, which is separate from the symbol, and which has the same name as the symbol. But only if it is told what to load, and this is done via the `.lib` or `.inc` SPICE directives, or by modifying the symbol to hold that information. LTspice will first search the local path for subcircuits containing that name. If it can't find any, it will search in the custom paths set in the *Control Panel*. If it can't find there, either, it will default to the two installation paths. In this case, it sees the *LR8.sub* first, located in the same folder as the schematic.

For your case, if you insist in placing these in your *%LocalAppData%*, then the only two files you need are *LR8.asy*, which you need to place in *%LocalAppData%/LTspiceXVII/lib/sym/* (or one of the subfolders), and *LR8.sub*, in *%LocalAppData/LTspiceXVII/lib/sub/*. Then you need to close LTspice and reopen it. If you placed the symbol in *sym/*, not in a subfolder, bringing up the component browser (<kbd>F2</kbd>) will show `LR8` listed there.

But, by itself, it will not do anything unless it is told what to look for. That's why you have to add the `.lib LR8.sub` directive. And, since the *LR8.sub* has been placed in the *sub/* filder, it doesn't need any additional paths (it's in the default path).

If you want to avoid this, too, you'll need to modify the symbol such that it loads the subcircuit everytime. Then <kbd>R-Click</kbd> on the symbol and edit its properties: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and edit the `ModelFile` line to be *LR8.sub*.

**Doing this will mean you won't be able to share your projects with anyone else without packing all the relevant symbols and libraries**.

To avoid that take example from the archive you downloaded and keep the symbol and the subcircuit together with the schematic you're working on. Pressing <kbd>S</kbd> and typing `.lib LR8.sub` is a trifle compared to building the schematic, and you'll never have problems with sharing (if you need to share).